# How to include a read-write (existing) SQLite database in an iOS app from Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sqlite

I'm trying to include a pre-created sqlite database from Xcode in my iOS app. The database needs to be updated when the app receives certain notifications (in JSON format) from a web server.

The database is included in the Xcode files and I see it inside the inspector.

The function I'm using to insert data inside my database is the following:

```
   Import SQLite
      

   func insertItem(item: Item){
            let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
            let description = Expression<String>("description")
            
            
            let bundle = Bundle.main
            let path = bundle.path(forResource: "DatabaseLocale", ofType: "sqlite")!
        
            let db = try! Connection("\(path)")
            
            let items = Table("Items")
            
            let insert = items.insert(id <- Int64(item.id), description <- item.description)
            
            do{
                let rowid = try! db.run(insert)
            } catch {
                print("cannot modify the database")
            }
            
            do{
                for itemID in try db.prepare(items){
                    print(itemID[id])
                    print(itemID[description])
                }
            } catch {
                print("couldn't connect to database")
            }
        }
```

Now, when I run the app inside the simulator, I get the result I want, so the new data the app receives is correctly written inside the database, but whenever I use my physical iPhone, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: attempt to write a readonly database (code: 8)
```

How do I make the SQLite database inside the iPhone app modifiable?

Comment: You cannot modify files inside the bundle. You need to copy your sqlite file from the bundle to the Documents folder, then read/write to **that** file. As a side note, unless you're choosing SQLite because you're already very familiar with it, you may want to look into CoreData instead.

Comment: Or, instead of the documents folder, the application support directory might be better.

Comment: I tried copyying that but it didn't help, maybe a possible solution could be creating the db when the app opens for the first time? In that case, will the database be kept in memory or will it be deleted when I reopen the app?